# In Django after loading {{form.media}} javascripts in the page stop working

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django

I am trying to use the [django-map-widgets](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets) in my project. However, after I load the map using
`{{location.media}} {{location.as_p}}`
, even though the map loads fine, the other javascript codes in the page stop working. For example the "logout link" which uses a javascript script:

**The Django form:**

```
class LocationDetails(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = ['location']
        widgets = {
            'lage': GoogleStaticOverlayMapWidget(zoom=12, thumbnail_size='50x50', size='640x640'),
        }
```

**The template section**

```
...

<h5 class="work-details-title font-alt mt-20">location</h5>
                            <p>{{ location_form.media }}

                                {{ location_form.lage }}
                            </p>
...
```

**The rendered HTML code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--
    Document Title
    =============================================
    -->
    <title>
        Ihr Dashboard
    </title>
    <!--
    Favicons
    =============================================
    -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"
          href="/static/assets/images/favicons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/static/assets/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/static/assets/images/favicons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!--
    Stylesheets
    =============================================

    -->
    <!-- Default stylesheets-->
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Template specific stylesheets-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:400i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/animate.css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/et-line-font/et-line-font.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/assets/lib/simple-text-rotator/simpletextrotator.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Main stylesheet and color file-->
    <link href="/static/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="color-scheme" href="/static/assets/css/colors/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--- JQuery --->
    <script src="/static/assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--- datepicker --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/>

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".onpage-navigation" data-offset="60">
<main>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top one-page" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span
                        class="sr-only">Base </span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Base</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/prof/">prof</a></li>
                    <li><a class="section-scroll" href="/prof/my_orders">orders</a></li>
                    <li><a class="section-scroll" href="/user/about-us">about-me</a></li>
                    <li><a class="section-scroll" href="/user/contact-us">contact-me</a></li>

                    <li><a class="section-scroll" id="signOutLink">logout</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="main">


        <section class="module-small bg-dark-90 about-page-header"
                 data-background="/static/assets/images/hero.png">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-center">
                        <div class="font-alt titan-title-size-3 m-0 p-0">Base Tyler</div>

                        <div class="titan-title-size-2 font-alt m-0 mb-0 pt-0">Willkommen</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="module-small">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row mb-10 mt-10">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
                        <div class="mb-20 mt-20">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <h3 class="font-alt mb-0">Profil</h3>
                        <hr class="divider-w mb-20">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">

                        <img
                                src="/media/uploads/provider/da2634cd-dc15-41ba-95af-a5196e64f661.jpeg"
                                alt="mraabs - service"/>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        <div class="work-details">

                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>Username: </strong><span class="font-serif">mraabs</span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Name: </strong><span
                                        class="font-serif">Base Tyler</span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Email: </strong><span class="font-serif">base@gmail.com</span>
                                </li>
                                <li><strong>Adresse: </strong><span class="font-serif">London</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5 class="work-details-title font-alt mt-20">Description</h5>
                            <p>Well!</p>

<!---- The place where the Google map widget is inserted ----->
                            <h5 class="work-details-title font-alt mt-20">location</h5>
                            <p>
                                <link href="/static/mapwidgets/css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" media="all"
                                      rel="stylesheet">
                                <script src="/static/mapwidgets/js/jquery_init.js"></script>
                                <script src="/static/mapwidgets/js/jquery.custom.magnific-popup.js"></script>


                                <a href="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.508900118663085%2C-0.13086899190500656&amp;markers=size%3Anormal%7Ccolor%3A%7Cicon%3A%7C51.508900118663085%2C-0.13086899190500656&amp;zoom=12&amp;size=640x640&amp;thumbnail_size=50x50&amp;scale=&amp;format=&amp;maptype=&amp;path=&amp;visible=&amp;style=&amp;language=&amp;region=&amp;key=AIzaSyDqbiV9mTMV0N2tfPLSP-YBhcuPjBCsj18"
                                   class="map-widget-overlay-link"><img
                                        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.508900118663085%2C-0.13086899190500656&amp;markers=size%3Anormal%7Ccolor%3A%7Cicon%3A%7C51.508900118663085%2C-0.13086899190500656&amp;zoom=12&amp;size=50x50&amp;thumbnail_size=50x50&amp;scale=&amp;format=&amp;maptype=&amp;path=&amp;visible=&amp;style=&amp;language=&amp;region=&amp;key=AIzaSyDqbiV9mTMV0N2tfPLSP-YBhcuPjBCsj18"></a>

                                <input type="hidden" name="lage"
                                       value="SRID=4326;POINT (-0.1308689919050066 51.50890011866309)"/>
                            </p>

<!---- end of the google map widget section -------->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        </section>


    </div>
    <div class="scroll-up"><a href="#totop"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i></a></div>


</main>


<form style='display: none;' method="post" action="/accounts/logout/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
           value="cQfxKwN3oLkGKf1QQKQkH5hx68Ahx2tcb32xbpOXpAjOxTAMBoB2aEDD7fsB2gCf">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/"/>
    <button id="signOutBtn" type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
<!--
JavaScripts
=============================================
-->
<script src="/static/assets/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/wow/dist/wow.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/jquery.mb.ytplayer/dist/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/lib/simple-text-rotator/jquery.simple-text-rotator.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/static/assets/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<!--- to move this if required also add condition to load it if required --->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#signOutLink', function () {
        $('#signOutBtn').click()
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser's Developer Tools shows [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heM9N.png) However, when I remove the `{{location.media}}` everything work as expected. I placed all the javascript files in the header too, but no luck.

I am not sure how to continue with debug this problem. I would appreciate it if you guide me on how to resolve this problem

Comment: Where are you adding the `{{ location.media }}` tag?

Comment: Pardon me, I am not sure what exactly do you mean. But, I have added the template snippet code and also in the html section I have added comment :<!---- The place where the Google map widget is inserted ----->: to indicate where the google map widget is starts and end (after rendering)